# Doctrine lifecycleCallbacks strange behaviour

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have defined lifecycleCallbacks in yaml as follows:

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [setCreatedAtValue]
    preUpdate: [setUpdatedAtValue]
```

The above has generated entities with the respective functions as follows:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setCreatedAtValue()
{
    if($this->created_at == null)
    {
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

Which looks all fine, right? However, when I try to open the sonata admin page, I get the following error

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@ORM\PrePersist" in method AppBundle\Entity\Article::setCreatedAtValue() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

I have never encountered this before and a bit confused about what to do. I am using symfony 2.7.6, Doctrine ORM version 2.5.1, Sonata Admin 2.3.7

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you defined your callbacks using yaml, you don´t need to define them again using annotations. Just remove the comments with the `@ORM\PrePersist` block before the function and everything will be fine.

If you wanted to use annotations to define your doctrine properties, you would need to import them before you can use them. To do so you would need to add this line at the beginning of your file:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I usually just rely on the Doctrine generated entities and have never had a problem until now. Looks like I'll need to be paying closer attention to change-logs.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue came with me.

In my case everything worked well until I did not Serialize my object in `JsonResponse`.

So problem was that previously I was not using that entity class (which was giving error) for sending `JsonResponse`, as soon as I tried to prepare `JsonResponse` containing that class, `JsonResponse` failed to serialize my class as it hadn't implemented `Serializable` interface.

This will happen if you will fetch objects with methods like `findAll` or `findBy` which returns Entity objects instead of php array.

So I just skipped those native methods and write doctrine query for fetching data.
You can also implement `Serializable` interface.

Comment: Worked Like charm.